# Hosting website from own webserver to domain name

Tags: iis-7.5, hosting, website, domain-name, settings

i've an domain name with no further options. Just the domain name. My site is running well on my own machine on IIS. So my localhost is showing the website. This website i want to show when i go to the specific domain name (e.q. www.something.com) All i see now is the "under construction" page of the compagny i bought the domain from.

I've tried serveral things but nothing does the job. So maybe you can help me out. Do i have to config my router? How do i configure the domain name part?

I'm stuck so any help is welcome.

Comment: You need to configure DNS.  I would highly recommend reading up on how DNS works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to designate name servers for your domain at the domain Registrar and set up the appropriate DNS records.

The domain Registrar probably has an FAQ that explains how to do this. If not, or if you have trouble understanding the steps needed, contact their support.